# Updating state will cause re-rendering and it will close Material UI Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

so I'm using Material Ui [Fullscreen Dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#full-screen-dialogs)
and everytime a state change, it will re-render and close the dialog box. what should i do?
how can i collect data from this dialog box ? I'm using `Context API` to update parent state.

```js
  const [advancedSearch, setAdvancedSearch] = useState({
    selectIdentify: "",
    type: "",
    gender: "",
    age: { from: "", to: "" },
    registerDate: { from: "", to: "" },
    and etc... (there are so many input field)
  });
```

```js
  <Dialog
          fullScreen
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          TransitionComponent={Transition}
        >
          <AppBar>
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton
                edge="start"
                onClick={handleClose}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography
                component="div"
              >
                Advanced Search
              </Typography>
              <Button
                startIcon={<SearchIcon />}
              >
                Create New Form
              </Button>
              <Button
                startIcon={<SearchIcon />}
                onClick={handleClose}
              >
                Search
              </Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <div>
            <AdvancedSearchContext.Provider
              value={{ advancedSearch, setAdvancedSearch }}
            >
              <Form1 />
              <Form2 />
              <Form3 /> 
            </AdvancedSearchContext.Provider>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
```

i know one solution is to have state in the three Form1,2,3 Children but in that case how should I collect it in the parent and send the data ?

Comment: When you set state to an object like that its value will be an object.  Updating any part of it will make the new state value a new object.  If you pass it via props, it will be seen as a new value and trigger a re-render.  This is because props are evaluated with a shallow-comparison, so a prop with an object value must be referentially equal to be considered unchanged.

Comment: What is your React version?